# Avoid in-app purchase App Store

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, qr-code, in-app

Our company sells both **digital and physical books**.

For each book we have a demo app where you can buy the full digital version with an in-app purchase.

For the users that **have bought the physical copy** of the book, **the digital content should be available for free** (with a QR code), so we need to by-pass the in-app purchase to show the content.

Does App Store allow a by-pass like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the Review Guidelines of the App Store, seems permissible:

> 3.1.3 “Reader” Apps: Apps may allow a user to access previously purchased content or content subscriptions (specifically: magazines,
>   newspapers, books, audio, music, video, access to professional
>   databases, VoIP, cloud storage, and approved services such as
>   educational apps that manage student grades and schedules), as well as
>   consumable items in multi-platform games, provided that you agree not
>   to directly or indirectly target iOS users to use a purchasing method
>   other than in-app purchase, and your general communications about
>   other purchasing methods are not designed to discourage use of in-app
>   purchase.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments

Nevertheless it seems like your app still has to go through in-app purchase to buy new digital content **from the app** and **must not discourage** the use of in-app purchase method **nor encourage** other method.

Hope it helps.